# UBUNTU 11.04 + PHP + POSTGRESQL Enhance performance

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I'm on this machine:

intel core 2 duo e8400 @3GHZ
4GB ram ddr2

php 5.3.6
pgsql 9.1

I'm running a php script that takes like 5 minutes on a mac with similar specs.
This php script, essentially, recreate a db importing some data into it.

On this computer it runs in more than 20 minutes.

The weird thing is the use of the CPU from both PHP & POSTGRESQL

```
 PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
 8408 postgres  20   0 2188m  44m  40m D    4  1.1   0:20.71 postgres                                                                                                                                          
 8407 gianps    20   0  380m 225m 6620 S    2  5.7   0:11.78 php


top - 16:08:32 up  3:35,  3 users,  load average: 1.26, 1.15, 0.80
Tasks: 187 total,   1 running, 185 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.8%us,  2.7%sy,  0.2%ni, 87.0%id,  5.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4056572k total,  2541972k used,  1514600k free,   117772k buffers
Swap:  3905532k total,        0k used,  3905532k free,   902048k cached
```

I setup the php (both cli and apache) to use as much ram as they need (memory limit -1) and tuned postgres to use:

shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 3072MB

Any suggestion to let this script use more ram & more cpu and run faster?

thanks

update:
after some investigation i found that that setting synchronous commit (in this situation) makes my script 10x faster.

```
set synchronous_commit to off;
```

since is not safe to make this option a default, i just switch it to off when needed..
to understand what synchronous commit does [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing data requires writing it to disk, so the duration of the process is likely given by the performance of the local storage system. If your Mac has a flashy SSD and the other box an IDE disk, the latter may easily be a lot slower. Use iostat to visualize disk throughput on both systems.

Another big performance factor for inserting/writing data is commit size, try inserting a lot of rows at once and then issue a commit only every few thousand rows. Or use the even faster "COPY FROM STDIN" method (this is proprietary to Postgresql).

Comment: Both computers got the same hard disk (sata 2 7200 rpm). I guess is some hidden value is locking php/postgres using more ram-cpu.

Comment: changing to synchronous commit to off solved my issues. Found it thanks to your infos about commits.